# RestController not work with MultiPartFile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i'm new on StackOverflow try to be as clear as possible.

I have a controller that take in input a MultipartFile,

[FE Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfbTQ.png)
it work well but if i call the RestController of my app it don't work.
[RestController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU3di.png)

This is the request that i have on @RequestBody
[Request @RequestBody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mypTt.png)

i tried with different consumes like consumes = "multipart / *" but they didn't work.

Could you give me some advice on what I need to do to be able to receive the multipart file as input in my custom request?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **@ModelAttribute**  instead of **@RequestBody**. and request with form-data instead of JSON format. Hope it should work.